# uwp app is reported to crash on launch but runs good on my computer

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

I submit my app to the Microsoft Store but Microsoft Store Team reports my app to crash on launch. However, when I build my app in either Debug mode or Release mode, it runs perfectly. I just don't know how to reproduce the crash which makes me unable to figure out what's going on within my app. And Microsoft team doesn't give my any other information about the crash.

Can anyone help me figure out why my app crashes? Or can anyone give me some hints on how to fix such crash?

My app does crash sometimes but that's about the frequency of once out of at least 20 builds. I submitted my app 3 times but they reports crash every time. So I don't think the crashes might share the same reason.

This is my [project link](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer).

Since it crashes on launch, it might have something to do with the `OnLaunched` function [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/App.xaml.cs).

And these are the links to the functions that I called in `OnLaunched`:

[Settings.Init](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Models/Settings.cs)

[MusicLibrary.Init](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/MusicLibraryPage.xaml.cs)

[MediaHelper.Init](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Helpers/MediaHelper.cs)

Comment: Your manifest says `MinVersion="10.0.0.0"`, but your program use the 10.0.17763.0 SDK. I suspect your program doesn't actually work on build 10.0.0.0. Bump the MinVersion to 10.0.17763.0.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks, that's possible. I'll try.

Comment: Your main page [uses a NavigationView](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/f29dfae3c1c0d148226c92e115c09890e993f71e/SMPlayer/MainPage.xaml#L22) which is not supported until 10.0.16299.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*App will work fine when it's local debug, but it will crash and be returned when it's submitted to the app store.*

When the Microsoft Store reviews an app, it usually tests with the app’s minimum running platform, so once your app uses an API that is not included in the minimum running platform, the app will crash immediately.

For example, if you use the property `Button.CornerRadius` to add rounded corners to the button, but before 1809, most of the controls did not have the property of `CornerRadius`. Once the application using this property runs on the Windows 10 platform below 1809, then it will crash.

---

So you'd better set up a virtual machine, load a system mirror of the lower system version, then package the application and put it in system for testing.

But sometimes, even if you know the cause of the problem, it is still difficult to locate the specific attribute of the control. Therefore, the quickest way is to modify the minimum runnable version of your application and modify it to the same level as your local computer system version.

But if you need to be compatible with more platforms, this requires targeted testing.

Best regards.

Comment: I have changed the min version and I am resubmitting my app. But I notice that for the package I previously submitted, the Device families is **Windows.Universal min version 10.0.17763.0** even though I used Win10 in my manifest. Do you think the version is still the main reason?

Comment: For most crash applications, yes. I recommend that you uninstall your own debug deployment application and install the release package to check if it will crash. If you want to determine the cause of the crash, you need to get the crash related error message.

Comment: The problem is that it also doesn't crash in release mode...My submission was finally successful but I just submitted another package for bug fixes and it crashes again...

Comment: Your crash report should describe the test environment. You can try to test it with the same environment, such as creating a virtual machine of the same system version.

Comment: They are using the good environment. Do you think the warnings from the taglib package might be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to first create appxupload bundle for x86 architecture only in release mode. Run & test Side-load version, Then submit to store. I also facing same issue in past due to some Nuget packages.

Comment: One of my Nuget package does give me some warnings. Do you think that would matter?